# Delete function doesn't work properly python tkinter sql

Tags: python, sql, tkinter

I'm creating student organizer and last functions I added is deleting the students from listbox. The problem occurs if I delete some student in the middle of the list box. It works once, then I can't delete the student which takes place of deleted student. I think it's something with indexes, but I can't find out what exactly. 
Load function is activated every time I click on the student using a mouse in the listbox.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter.filedialog

class StudentManager :
    db_conn = 0
    theCursor = 0
    curr_student = 0


    def setup_db(self):
        self.db_conn = sqlite3.connect('student.db')
        self.theCursor = self.db_conn.cursor()

        try:
            self.db_conn.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists Students(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, FName TEXT NOT NULL, LName TEXT NOT NULL, Telefon TEXT NOT NULL, Wiek TEXT NOT NULL, PName TEXT NOT NULL);")

            self.db_conn.commit()

        except sqlite3.OperationalError:
            print("ERROR : Table not created")


    def dodaj_student(self):
        self.db_conn.execute("INSERT INTO Students (FName, LName, Telefon, Wiek, PName)" +
                                                   "VALUES ('" +
                                                   self.imie_value.get() + "', '" +
                                                   self.nazwisko_value.get() + "', '" +
                                                   self.telefon_value.get() + "', '" +
                                                   self.wiek_value.get() + "', '" +
                                                  self.imierodzica_value.get() + "')")



        self.imie.delete(0, "end")
        self.nazwisko.delete(0, "end")
        self.telefon.delete(0, "end")
        self.wiek.delete(0, "end")
        self.imierodzica.delete(0, "end")

        self.update_listbox()

    def load_student(self, event=None):
        lb_widget = event.widget
        index = str(lb_widget.curselection()[0] + 1)  #????
        index2 = str(lb_widget.curselection()[0])
        self.curr_student = index
        self.curr_student2 = index2

        try:
            result = self.theCursor.execute("SELECT ID, FName, LName, Telefon, Wiek, PName FROM Students WHERE ID=" + index)

            for row in result:

                stud_id = row[0]
                stud_fname = row[1]
                stud_lname = row[2]
                stud_telefon = row[3]
                stud_wiek = row[4]
                stud_pname = row[5]

                self.imie_value.set(stud_fname)
                self.nazwisko_value.set(stud_lname)
                self.telefon_value.set(stud_telefon)
                self.wiek_value.set(stud_wiek)
                self.imierodzica_value.set(stud_pname)

        except sqlite3.OperationalError:
            print("The Table Doesn't Exist")

        except:
            print("2 : Couldn't Retrieve Data From Database")



    def update_listbox(self):

        self.list_box.delete(0, END)

        try:
            result = self.theCursor.execute("SELECT ID, FName, LName, Telefon, Wiek, PName FROM Students")

            for row in result:
                stud_id = row[0]
                stud_fname = row[1]
                stud_lname = row[2]
                stud_telefon = row[3]
                stud_wiek = row[4]
                stud_pname = row[5]

                self.list_box.insert(stud_id,
                                stud_fname + " " +
                                stud_lname + " " +
                                stud_telefon + " " +
                                stud_wiek + " " +
                                stud_pname)

        except sqlite3.OperationalError:
            print("The Table Doesn't Exist")

        except:
            print("1: Couldn't Retrieve Data From Database")


    def delete_student(self):

        try:
            self.db_conn.execute("DELETE FROM Students WHERE ID=" + self.curr_student)
            self.db_conn.commit()

        except sqlite3.OperationalError:
            print("Data couldn't be Deleted")

        self.imie.delete(0, "end")
        self.nazwisko.delete(0, "end")
        self.telefon.delete(0, "end")
        self.wiek.delete(0, "end")
        self.imierodzica.delete(0, "end")

        self.update_listbox()



    def __init__(self, root):

        self.window_is_open = False
        self.notatnik_window = False
        root.title("Student Manager")
        root.geometry("340x480")

        # ------ 1st Row ------
        imie_label = Label(root, text="Imie")
        imie_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)

        self.imie_value = StringVar(root, value="")
        self.imie = ttk.Entry(root,
                                textvariable=self.imie_value)
        self.imie.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)

        nazwisko_label = Label(root, text="Nazwisko")
        nazwisko_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)

        self.nazwisko_value = StringVar(root, value="")
        self.nazwisko = ttk.Entry(root,
                                        textvariable=self.nazwisko_value)
        self.nazwisko.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)

        telefon_label = Label(root, text="Telefon")
        telefon_label.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)

        self.telefon_value = StringVar(root, value="")
        self.telefon = ttk.Entry(root,
                                textvariable=self.telefon_value)
        self.telefon.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)

        wiek_label = Label(root, text="Wiek")
        wiek_label.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)

        self.wiek_value = StringVar(root, value="")
        self.wiek = ttk.Entry(root,
                    textvariable=self.wiek_value)
        self.wiek.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)

        imierodzica_label = Label(root, text="Imie rodzica")
        imierodzica_label.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)

        self.imierodzica_value = StringVar(root, value="")
        self.imierodzica = ttk.Entry(root,
                                    textvariable=self.imierodzica_value)
        self.imierodzica.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)


        self.submit_button = ttk.Button(root, width=23,
                                        text="Dodaj",
                                        command = lambda: self.dodaj_student())
        self.submit_button.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)

        self.edit_button = ttk.Button(root, width=23,
                                        text="Edytuj",
                                        command = lambda: self.update_student())

        self.edit_button.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)


        self.more_button = ttk.Button(root, width=23,
                                        text="Wiecej",
                                        command = lambda: self.more_student())
        self.more_button.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)

        self.delete_button = ttk.Button(root, width=23,
                                        text="Usun",
                                        command = lambda: self.delete_student())
        self.delete_button.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)

        scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)

        self.list_box = Listbox(root)
        self.list_box.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.load_student)
        self.list_box.insert(1, "Students Here")
        self.list_box.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=5, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W+E)



        self.setup_db()

        self.update_listbox()




root = Tk()
studManager = StudentManager(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to provide testable code. You have given us a section of a class but not what we need to test this. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: _" then I can't delete the student which takes place of deleted student"_ - why can't you? What happens when you try?

Comment: Please read the link I posted in my last comment. Also your test code is not indented.

Comment: @BryanOakley  The data is still in the list box. It doesn't disappear, hard to say if it's deleted from the database but for sure not from the list box.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech Thanks for your patience, I'm going to check the post and correct mine

Comment: Ok, I've edited my first post. I hope it's ok now. I will explain also the problem once again, more accurate. When you add some students do the list box (button dodaj/function dodaj_student) and then you want to remove some of them from list box it works at first, but then if you want to delete second/third student it stops to work. After clicking usun button(delete; function delete_student)data of student doesn't disappear from the list box.